# Why Solidity no deterministic AST

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile

Question: I read that [why recompile all truffle](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/faq#why-do-i-have-to-recompile-all-contracts-for-truffle)

> The technical reason is that since Solidity does not produce deterministic ASTs, the plugins are unable to resolve references correctly if they are not from the same compiler run.

can anyone point me to the reason why Solidity does not (chooses not to) produce deterministic AST?